# Spring Boot Exception not shown in the console or client even if thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, runtimeexception

I'm coding an application where there's a user API accessible to someone with the right authentication (form authentication). The problem is that runtime exceptions are not displayed in the console nor the client when they in fact happen.

Part of Service:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AppUserService {

    private AppUserRepository repository;


    public AppUser getUserByUsername(String username) {
        if (!repository.existsByUsername(username)) {
            log.error("Cannot find user with username: {}", username);
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User with username '" + username + "' not found");
        }
        log.info("Fetching user with username: {}", username);
        return repository.findAppUserByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AppUserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private AppUserRepository repository;
    private AppUserService underTest;

    @BeforeEach
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    void setUp() {
        openMocks(this);
        underTest = new AppUserService(repository);
    }

    // [...]

    @Test
    void cannotGetUserByUsernameWhenUsernameIsNotInDB() {
        // given
        given(repository.existsByUsername(any())).willReturn(false);
        String username = "Adam";
        // when
        // then
        assertThatThrownBy(() -> underTest.getUserByUsername(username))
                .isInstanceOf(UserNotFoundException.class)
                .hasMessageContaining("User with username '" + username + "' not found");
        then(repository).shouldHaveNoMoreInteractions();
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Both the unit test and the fact that this log `log.error("Cannot find user with username: {}", username);` is printed to the console ensure that the throw statement is reached so I guess it's something that has to do with spring

Part of Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, UUID> {

    AppUser findAppUserByUsername(String username);

n   // [...]
}
```

Exception Class:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public UserNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
# info
info.application.name=@name@
info.application.version=@version@
info.application.description=@description@
info.application.jdk=@java.version@
info.application.groupId=@groupId@

# DB
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/auth
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# server
server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xdavide9</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-Auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring-Auth</name>
    <description>Form based authentication made with Spring Boot.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I really don't know where this is coming fromn so I included application.properties and pom too. I even tried to create a handler using @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler and that way I can return a response entity to the client atleast but still nothing to the console.

Comment: How is `underTest` created, and what are the annotations on your test class?

Comment: I have added these details to the question